# Php schedule events

Tags: php, android, curl

I have php script hosted in ftp server.

Its accessed from android app.

I did enabled Google Cloud Messaging in android and also php script.

So I want to send message every one hour.

So I need php schedule for trigger every one hour.
Message is constant.

My php code is:

```
<?php

define( "API_ACCESS_KEY", "***********************");

// Message to be sent
$message = "welcome to android app";

//RegistrationIds
 $registrationid = "******************";

//call to gcm notification 
send_push_notification($registrationid,$message);

//gcm push notification function 
function send_push_notification($registrationids,$messages){

//GCM Implementation Code 
// Set POST variables
$url = "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send";


$fields = array(
            'registration_ids'  => array($registrationids),
            'data'              => array( "message" => $messages ),
            );

$headers = array( 
                'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
                'Content-Type: application/json'
            );

// Open connection
$ch = curl_init();

// Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );

cur_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );

// Execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

// Close connection
curl_close($ch);

echo $result;

}
?>
```

I want to call send push notification method every one hour.

Comment: Have a look at [Cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)

Comment: But how to add schedule in my script.Any configuration needed..

Comment: Create [cron-job](http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml) using php

Answer (score 2):

You can use cron job for this. You dont have to add anything to the PHP script. Just running it every hour will solve the issue. Below is how you can add a cronjob. I believe you are on a Linux server.

```
0 * * * *  /usr/bin/php /path/to/your/php/script.php
```

See this link to see how you can add/edit/delete cron tab - http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/